# Span class styling

Tags: css, html

I dont get it, it seems so simple. I want to add a span style to 
the "Hello" text with a .class

http://www.mysecretathens.gr/kulte_test/index.html

Why doesnt this .greeting class work? It only becames 60pixels when I put it like that

```
<span style="font-size:60px;">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your CSS should be `.greeting{ font-size: 60px }`

Comment: <span style="font-size: 150%;background:#ff00ff">micro average ROC</span>

Comment: <span style="font-size: 150%;color:#0000ff">macro average ROC</span>

Answer (score 4):

You havent closed a CSS class above it. Put a curly brace righ before:

```
::selection{
```

like so:

```
#container2 {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("white_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% -28px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #636161;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
::selection {
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #da0225;
}
```

Comment: @MikeSmithDev You only get seconds for questions like these ;-) You shoulda seen me scramblin lol

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't close the #container2 css rule.

```
#container2 {
background-color: #ebebeb;
height: 400px;
background-image: url("white_arrow.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% -28px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 80px;
text-align: center;
color: #636161;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: oh my god, you are right. Blame it on the late hours, damn! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use spaces between your curly braces!

(it rhymed).

oh and the real issue with your site is #container2 is missing a closing }.

Comment: ah i see u changed the comment after the others' solutions.

Comment: was an attempt to humor, with a delayed edit. :)

Comment: i'm anyway deleting the answer, but in my defense, i hadn't seen the other answers.